# Network communication in 2Hosts

Tags: linux, networking, route

We have 2 Linux Hosts each has 2 Nic Cards with below IP addresses,`ech0` and `eth1` are in different network , `Host1:eth1` and `Host2:eth1` are connected by direct cable, due to some Hardware issue N/W cable got bad, Is there any way to communicate between `Host1:eth1` and `Host2:eth1` ?

In Normal conditions: Communication from `Host1:eth0 to Host2:eth1` and `Host2:eth0 to Host1:eth1` is not working , i checked by this by `TRACEROUTE` -I command (`Host1# traceroute -i eth0 10.1.1.201 or Host2# traceroute -i eth0   10.1.1.200`)

===========================

```
Host1:
eth0  : 10.162.100.200/24
eth1  : 10.1.1.200/24

Host2:
eth0  : 10.162.100.201/24
eth1  : 10.1.1.201/24
```

==========================

Comment: I don't really understand your config.  Are host1 and host2 physically attached to each other with a working network cable?  Are they attached to the same switch/router?  Are they in the same building?

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Single static routes on HOST1(route add -host 10.1.1.200 gw 10.162.100.200 eth0) is not work ,since HOST1:eth0(10.162.100.200) don't know about HOST2:eth1(10.1.1.201). Traceroute shows this (HOST1# traceroute -i eth0 10.1.1.201 or HOST2# traceroute -i eth0 10.1.1.200). I need multiple static routes ,i am not sure how to write ROUTE/IPTABLES commands for below static routes. 1)Need static route on HOST1, If any packets with source address HOST1:eth1(10.1.1.200) and destination address HOST2:eth1(10.1.1.201) ,Then Forward packets to HOST1:eth0(10.162.100.200). 2)One mo

Comment: Above one can simplified as for packets with "source address HOST1:eth1(10.1.1.200) and destination address HOST2:eth1(10.1.1.201)" HOST1:eth1(10.1.1.200) => HOST1:eth0 (10.162.100.200)=> HOST2:eth0(10.162.100.201) =>HOST2:eth1(10.1.1.201) Need static routes for above path

Comment: Tony, HOST1 and HOST2 are in same building ,HOST1:eth1 and HOST2:eth1 are directly connected by crossover cable, but cable is not working ,HOST1:eth0 and HOST2:eth0 are connected to Office Network VIA switch ,from Workstations we can access HOST1:eth0 and HOST2:eth0 only, we can't access HOST1:eth1 and HOST2:eth1 since they are in different N/W with crossover cable. I would like to send packets from HOST1:eth1 to HOST2:eth1 using HOST1:eth0 and HOST2:eth0 interfaces. ==========Config=================
Host1:
eth0 : 10.162.100.200/24
eth1 : 10.1.1.200/24 Host2:
eth0 : 10.162.100.201/24
eth1 : 10

Comment: As per SpacemanSpiff suggestion ,i will try with below commands Please let me know if anything wrong with below commands on HOST1
======== route add -host 10.1.1.201 gw 10.162.100.201 eth0 (HOST1:eth1(10.1.1.200) => HOST1:eth0 (10.162.100.200)=> HOST2:eth0(10.162.100.201) =>HOST2:eth1(10.1.1.201)) on HOST2
======== route add -host 10.1.1.200 gw 10.162.100.200 eth0 (HOST2:eth1(10.1.1.201) => HOST2:eth0 (10.162.100.201)=> HOST1:eth0(10.162.100.200) =>HOST1:eth1(10.1.1.200))

Comment: @Vijay - STOP adding comments as answers, this is a question and answer site, nothing else, if you carry on we'll just destroy your account.

Answer (score 3):

This should be a pretty simple case of routes and metrics. When eth1's link is up, it is a "connected" network which should have a priority and take precedence, so communication between the hosts is direct.

However, if you set a static route on Host1 pointing to host2's eth0 address as a gateway for the host2's eth1 interface, it should work when the link is down hard.

You would do the opposite on the other host.

Comment: A single static route will be sufficient on each host. As for iptables configuration I'm not familiar.